# Back button(google chrome) need to put two times for go back, how to remove this problem?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a news list page and when i enter in some news-post and put (google chrome back arrow) i go again to news list, But when i put back arrow again i be back in news-post where just returned from. If you repeat the process again, it will normally go to where they were before the page of the news-list.
How to remove this problem?

[This is news list page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3k233.png)

[image: News list page]

Comment: Can you share some code? which will help the community to get you a better answer.

Comment: Would be nice if you can add more information or some code so people can understand what you are trying to achieve.
And I guess this will solve your problem by using `replaceState()` in history API but also depends on how you implement it. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History_API